# Need help reverse engineering a CRC16

Tags: reverse-engineering, network-protocols, crc, crc16

I'm trying to connect to the Safecom TA-810 (badge/registration system) to automate the process of calculating how long employee's have worked each day. Currently this is done by:

1. Pulling the data into the official application
2. Printing a list of all 'registrations'
3. Manually entering the values from the printed lists into our HR application

This is a job that can take multiple hours which we'd like to see automated. So far the official tech support has been disappointing and refused to share any details.

Using wireshark I have been capturing the UDP transmissions and have pretty much succeeded in understanding how the protocol is built up. I'm only having issues with what i suppose is a CRC field. I don't know how it is calculated (CRC type and parameters) and using which fields ...

This is how a message header looks like:

```
D0 07 71 BC BE 3B 00 00

D0 07 - Message type
71 BC - This i believe is the CRC
BE 3B - Some kind of session identifier. Stays the same for every message after the initial message (initial message has '00 00' as value)
00 00 - Message number. '01 00', '02 00', '03 00'
```

Some examples:

```
Header only examples
E8 03 17 FC 00 00 00 00 -> initial request (#0, no session nr)
D0 07 71 BC BE 3B 00 00 -> Initial response (#0, device sends a session nr)
4C 04 EF BF BE 3B 06 00 -> Message #6, still using the same session # as the initial response

Larger example, which has data
0B 00 07 E1 BE 3B 01 00 7E 45 78 74 65 6E 64 46 6D 74
```

I've also been trying to figure this out by reading the disassembled code from the original application. The screenshot below happens before the socket.sendto and seems to be related.

[image: original application code]

Any help will be extremely appreciated.

**EDIT**: Made some success with debugging the application using ollydbg. The CRC appears in register (reversed) EDX at the selected line in the following screenshot.

[image: crc showing up]

Comment: Been making some good progress debugging the flow. Seems to be much easier than a CRC16. They are just adding all bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to create a php script that does the CRC calculation by debugging the application using OllyDbg.

The CRC is calculated by Adding up every 2 bytes (every short). if the result is larger than a short, the 'most significant short' is added to the 'least significant short' until the result fits in a short. Finally, the CRC (short) is inverted.

I'll add my php script for completeness:

```
<?php
function CompareHash($telegram)
{
  $telegram = str_replace(" ", "", $telegram);
  $telegram_crc = substr($telegram, 4, 4);
  $telegram = str_replace($telegram_crc, "0000", $telegram);

  echo "Telegram: ", $telegram, ', Crc: ', $telegram_crc, ' (', hexdec($telegram_crc), ')<br />';

  $crc = 0; 
  $i = 0;

  while ($i < strlen($telegram)) 
  {
    $short = substr($telegram, $i, 4);

    if (strlen($short) < 4) $short = $short . '00';

    $crc += hexdec($short);
    $i += 4;
  }

  echo "Crc: ", $crc, ', inverse: ', ~$crc;

  // Region "truncate CRC to Int16"
  while($crc > hexdec('FFFF'))
  {
    $short = $crc & hexdec ('FFFF');

    // Region "unsigned shift right by 16 bits"
    $crc = $crc >> 16;
    $crc = $crc & hexdec ('FFFF');
    // End region

    $crc =  $short + $crc;
  }
  // End region

  // Region "invert Int16"
  $crc = ~$crc;
  $crc = $crc & hexdec ('FFFF');
  // End region

  echo ', shifted ', $crc;

  if (hexdec($telegram_crc) == $crc)
  {
    echo "<br />MATCH!!! <br />";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<br />failed .... <br />";
  }
}

$s1_full = "E8 03 17 FC 00 00 00 00";
$s2_full = "D0 07 71 BC BE 3B 00 00";
$s3_full = "D0 07 4E D4 E1 23 00 00";
$s4_full = "D0 07 35 32 BE 3B 07 00   7E 44 65 76 69 63 65  4E    61 6D 65 3D 54 41 38 31 30 00";
$s5_full = "0B 00 39 6C BE 3B 05 00   7E 52 46 43 61 72 64  4F    6E";

CompareHash($s1_full);
CompareHash($s2_full);
CompareHash($s3_full);
CompareHash($s4_full);
CompareHash($s5_full);
?>
```

Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [CRC RevEng](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/).  If you can correctly identify the data that the CRC is operating on and the location of the CRC, you should be able to determine the CRC parameters.  If it is a CRC.

Comment: Been trying to find out more by looking at the assembly code made by ollydbg or ida pro. But so far without luck. I have no idea which field are used and if it's even a CRC16 or a different implementation. It's a big undertaking when having no experience with assembly.